# How to detect simultaneous onPress events in react native?

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm trying to set a react native app that plays sounds when the user touches buttons.  This works fine when touching one button at a time.

However, it appears that only one `onPressIn` function can run at once.  But I want to be able to press multiple buttons simultaneously.  This is for cases where you might want to hold a long note and then play a rapid percussion sound over it.

My components look like:

```
<TouchableHighlight onPressIn={this.padPress.bind(this, padNum)} underlayColor="gray">
  <View style={[padWidth]}></View>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

Is there a way to detect multiple button pushes at once?  Or another way to achieve this functionality?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever end up figuring out how to do this??

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you need is the Pan Responder

Documentation: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/next/docs/panresponder.html

PanResponder reconciles several touches into a single gesture. It makes single-touch gestures resilient to extra touches, and can be used to recognize simple multi-touch gestures.

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't work either.  I tried registering to `onPanResponderGrant` and  `onPanResponderMove`, but both only respond to the initial touch event.  If I hold a finger and click again on the same view, the functions do not fire again.  Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Using onTouchStart, onTouchEnd props of View component you can achieve simultaneous onPress on different components on a screen.

For detailed explanation with code snippet check this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42779656/2131857