# Getting simultaneously click and move events on react native

Tags: react-native, multi-touch

I'm trying to manage multi-touches events with a `PanResponder` on react-native but I am struggling on the following:

- If using the `TouchableOpacity` component, I can't move at the same time onto the PanResponser
- If using [that way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42779656/3397563), I can't get the info of 2 events at the same time

The application I want to build contains movable zone + clickable zone and they must be used at the same time.

The journey I want to achieve with that is:

- user pressIn on the button
- user move an element on the panResponder
- user pressOut the button

Any ides

Thanks in advance

PS: no it's not drag & drop element

Regards

Comment: did you ever figure out how to do this?