# How to support multi touch for Android using react native

Tags: react-native, multi-touch, panresponder

I am using react native to create a dialpad in my application. the problem I am facing is that when dialpad buttons are pressed one at a time it works fine but when I click two buttons let's say number 1 and number 3 at the same time then nothing happens. However this problem was resolved for IOS using the following link:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42779656/23600788

```
<View>
  <View onTouchStart={()=>this.console("Button 2 Clicked")}>
    <Text>BUTTON 2</Text>
  </View>
  <View 
    onTouchStart={()=>this.console('Button 1 pressed')}
    onTouchEnd={()=>this.console('Button 1 released')}>
      <Text>BUTTON 1</Text>
  </View>
</View>
```

But this method does not work for android as when I hold down number 1 and then with other finger if i press number 3 then it again prints number 1.

Does anyone have any valid solution for this?

I am new to react native so please let me know if I am missing anything to add or mention here.

I am expecting multi touch support on Android same as in iOS.